# How to handle events for elements added by javascript ? without .on() jQuery?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've read alot of answers about my question but they are all about using `.on()` of jQuery, I'm in the process of learning Javascript, I wanna know how to handle events of newly created elements by JavaScript.

I've tried using `addEventListener` it's fired in the proccess of adding the element to the DOM, and not when the event occures!

Comment: Please post a code sample of what you tried, then explain what you are expecting to happen and what is going wrong

Comment: Which event did you bind your event listener?

Comment: you can bind eventListener to the element after the element's creation. In other words, create the element in js, then bind event listener to it

Comment: See #4 from this tutorial for an example: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference/

Comment: i have a text field and button, what is in the text field have to be added in <ul> as <li id="theItem">.. till here is all good, everything get added, the problem here is, when the <li> get added i want to handle an event which is mouseover to show some X within <a> tag also added under <li>, when i write addEventListener in click button event, it get fired even before it's get added to <ul>, with .on('mouseover', 'li', function) it's DONE!, but with addEventListener, no it won't !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you pass a reference to the event handler instead of calling it when you set it up. In other words, do this:

```
var handler = function(ev) { /* ... */ };

el.addEventListener("click", handler);
```

But **don't do this:**

```
var handler = function(ev) { /* ... */ };

el.addEventListener("click", handler());
```

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental thing is to hook the event on a container that you'll be adding the elements to. Most events *bubble*, and so (for instance) a click on a child element bubbles up to the parent element.

So say you have:

```
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

and you do this:

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
});
setInterval(function() {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "Added " + new Date();
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(li);
}, 2000);
```

Now we have new `li`s being added every couple of seconds. Clicking the list item will show its contents, because the click bubbles to the parent container, which is where we've hooked the click. `e.target` is a reference to the element where the event *originated*.

This is called *event delegation*.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/esoZiwA/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/esoZiwA/1/edit)

If you have elements within the child elements, you may have to look at `e.target.parentNode` or `e.target.parentNode.parentNode`, etc., to find the one you care about. (This usually involves a loop, going to each parent node in turn, stopping when you've reached the element on which you hooked the event.)

---

Side note: Using jQuery **is** using JavaScript (unless you use CoffeeScript, TypeScript, Dart, or some other language). jQuery is a *library*, not a language.